# What happens to client message if Server does not exist in UDP Socket programming?

Tags: udp

I ran the client.java only when I filled the form and pressed send button, it was jammed and I could not do anything.
Is there any explanation for this?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juLEa.png)

Comment: Please always add detailed explanation, and what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; the [User Datagram Protocol (UDP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is "fire-and-forget".

> **Unreliable** – *When a UDP message is sent, it cannot be known if it will reach its destination*; it could get lost along the way. *There is no concept of acknowledgment*, retransmission, or timeout.

So if a UDP message is sent and nobody listens then the packet is just dropped. (UDP packets can also be silently dropped due to other network issues/congestion.)

While there *could* be a prior-error such as resolving the IP for the server (eg. an invalid hostname) or attempting to use an invalid IP, *once the UDP packet is out the door, it's out the door and is considered "successfully sent".*

Now, if a program is waiting on a response that never comes (ie. the server is down or packet was "otherwise lost") then that could be .. problematic.

That is, this code which requires a UDP response message to continue would "hang":

```
 sendUDPToServerThatNeverResponds();

 // There is no guarantee the server will get the UDP message,
 // much less that it will send a reply or the reply will get back
 // to the client..
 waitForUDPReplyFromServerThatWillNeverCome();
```

Since UDP has no reliability guarantee or retry mechanism, this must be handled in code. For example, in the above maybe the code would wait for 1 second and retry sending a packet, and after 5 seconds of no responses it would report an error to the client.

```
sendUDPToServerThatMayOrMayNotRespond();

while (i++ < 5) {
   reply = waitForUDPReplyForOneSecond();
   if (reply)
      break;
}

if (reply)
   doSomethingAwesome();
else
   showErrorToUser();
```

Of course, "just using TCP" can often make these sorts of tasks simpler due to the stream and reliability characteristics that the [Transmission Control Protoocol (TCP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol) provides. For example, the pseudo-code above is not very robust as the client *must also be prepared to handle latent/slow UDP packet arrival from previous requests*.

(Also, given the current "screenshot", the code might be as flawed as `while(true) {}` - make sure to provide an SSCCE and relevant code with questions.)